# Как запустить python скрипт записанный в переменную

Tags: python

Всем привет. У меня есть переменная с python скриптом:

```
Script=(
'''
Hello="Hello, world"
print(Hello)
'''
)
```

И мне нужно запустить этот скрипт в этом файле, а не записывать его в другой файл и вызывать с помощью:

```
import os
os.startfile("имя файла")
```

Comment: Какую исходную задачу вы пытаетесь решить? Т.к. исполнять произвольный код опасно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того что бы перевести строку в "cкрипт" используйте `exec()`. Например:

```
Script=(
'''
Hello="Hello, world"
print(Hello)
'''
)
exec(Script) #Hello, world
```

Это работает отлично но имеет проблемы с безопасностью, например если вы получаете строку от пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо BlueScreen . На счёт строки от пользователя вы правы.